# Spring MVC dynamic datasource not hibernate

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

MySQL database has 6 databases in it, in which one database is common, 5 databases belong to different company, I want the company to login with the user ID and password, then the database of the same company gets connected.
How will[image]

Comment: Going into the common database will check which company employee's user id and password hai and that company's database will be connected and will check at the time of login.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using multiple databases in JPA. In the config file, you can write your logic to check which database you want to give access to a particular user. [See](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) this for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Going into the common database will check which company employee's user id and password hai and that company's database will be connected and will check at the time of login.